# XmlDocument Load unauthorized

Tags: iis, xmldocument

.cshtml file with the following code:

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load("http://remote_server/login/MyService.asmx/GetSearchData?Search="test"
```

returns **"System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized"** from some IIS servers but works fine on others:

- IIS in Windows 10: Works
- IIS server on SmarterASP.net: Works
- Started from Visual Studio Community 2013 (version 12) .NET 4.6: Works
- Started from Visual Studio Community 2015 (version 14) .NET 4.6: Returns error above
- IIS 7 on windows server 2008 R2 .NET 4.0: Returns error above

Is this a IIS configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange error, but since the webservice was on the same server as this page (windows server, last line above), we changed the address for the xd.load to:

```
xd.Load("http://localhost/login/MyService.asmx/GetSearchData?Search="test"
```

Worked fine then.